# How to mock the dependency injection object in unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

My project requires unit testing. I am using constructor dependency injection in my controller. When I mock the injected dependency object in my unit testing project and call it in a test method. Returns null in all cases.

Controller Class:

```
public class Owner:Controller
{
    private readonly IComRepository repository;
    private readonly DbContext context;
    
    public Owner(IComRepository repository, DbContext context)
    {
      this.repository=repository;
      this.context=context;
    }

    [HttpGet("GetAllTypes")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllTypes()
    {
      var ownerTypes=repository.GetTypes();
        return Ok(ownerTypes);
    }
}
```

My Repository Class

```
public Interface IComRepository
{
    IList<Type> GetTypes();
}
        
public Class ComRepository : IComRepository
{
    private readonly DbContext context;
    public ComRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        this.context=context;
    }
    public IList<Type> GetTypes()
    {
        var allTypes= context.Types.ToList();
        return allTypes;
    }
}
```

Now I need to test the GetAllTypes methods in my controller class. My Test Class is below mentioned:

```
using moq;
[TestClass]
public Class OwnerTest
{
    public OwnerTest()
    {
        var mockIcomrepo = new Mock<IComRepository>();
        var mockDbcontext = new Mock<Dbcontext>();
        OwnerController owner = new OwnerController(mockDbContext.Object, mockIcomrepo.Object);
    
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetTypes()
    {
        var allTypes= owner.GetAllTypes(); //It's not trigger to my controller
        Assert.AreEqual(5,allTypes.count());
    }
}
```

How can I do it? Any one know the answer for this question.

Comment: the mock repo has not be setup to do anything so it will return null by default.

Comment: Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better understanding of how to use MOQ

Comment: if answer solved you problem, can you mark it as answer

Answer (score 8):

As @Nkosi mentioned you have to use moq setup. Define your mocks outside constructor and initalize them in test class's constructor.

```
using moq;
[TestClass]
public Class OwnerTest
{
    private readonly IComRepository _mockRepository;
    private readonly OwnerControler _ownerController;
    
    //your mock data
    private readonly IList<Type> _mockData; 

    public OwnerTest()
    {
        _mockRepository= new Mock<IComRepository>();

        _ownerController = new OwnerController(mockDbContext.Object, mockIcomrepo.Object);
        _mockData = new IList<Type>{"Data1","Data2","Data3","Data4","Data5"};

    }
    
    //choose better names for testing a method 
    //e.g. by using a convention like MethodName_StateUnderTest_ExpectedResult;
    
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetAllTypes() 
    {
        _mockRepository.Setup(p=>p.GetAllTypes()).Returns(mockData);

        var result= _ownerController.GetAllTypes();
        var okResult=Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(result)
        var returnTypes=Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IList<Type>>(okResult.Value);
        Assert.AreEqual(5,returnTypes.count());
    }
}
```

Also, why you inject your dbcontext to controller?your repository should depend dbcontext not controller.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more complete, improved example of the pattern suggested in the answer from @Baris Can Yilmaz. I recommend making unit tests as granular as possible, ensuring all basic test cases are covered by individual tests, and structuring each test in the demonstrated form of 'Arrange, Act, Assert'.

```
using Moq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Tests.UnitTests.Owner
{
    [TestClass]
    public class OwnerControllerTest : MockDbTestBase
    {
        private readonly Mock<IComRepository> _mockRepository;
        private readonly OwnerController _ownerController;

        private readonly List<string> _mockData = new List<string> { "Data1", "Data2", "Data3", "Data4", "Data5" };

        public const int ExpectedNumberOfTypes = 5; // Define a constant

        public OwnerControllerTest()
        {
            _mockRepository = new Mock<IComRepository>();

            _ownerController = new OwnerController(MockDbContext.Object, _mockRepository.Object);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void GetAllTypes_ReturnsOkObjectResult()
        {
            // Arrange
            _mockRepository.Setup(p => p.GetAllTypes()).Returns(_mockData);

            // Act
            var result = _ownerController.GetAllTypes();

            // Assert
            Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(result);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void GetAllTypes_ReturnsExpectedNumberOfTypes()
        {
            // Arrange
            _mockRepository.Setup(p => p.GetAllTypes()).Returns(_mockData);

            // Act
            var result = _ownerController.GetAllTypes();

            // Assert
            var okResult = Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(result);
            var returnTypes = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IList<string>>(okResult.Value);
            Assert.AreEqual(ExpectedNumberOfTypes, returnTypes.Count);
        }
    }
}

public class MockDbTestBase
{
    protected Mock<YourDbContext> MockDbContext { get; private set; }

    public MockDbTestBase()
    {
        MockDbContext = new Mock<YourDbContext>();
    }
}
```